# Is there a way to tell how much extra heal and shield power you have?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am playing Soraka in League of Legends and her main role is to heal her allies, so shes buys items to help. Some of the best items for Soraka are items that give more healing power for example the item Redemption:[Redemption LoL item](https://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/item/redemption-336)

If you look at the third stat it gives it says, `+20% heal and shield power` many other items also offer this. In the champions sidebar you can see all their stats and abilities, but I can't find extra heal and shield power anywhere. So my question is, can you tell how much extra heal and shield power you have without counting it up by yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Updated answer

#### Certain items and runes display this value in their tooltips

Some, but not all, items that grant Heal and shield power will show this value. I was unable to find when these fields were added to their tooltips. As of this edit:

- Staff of Flowing Water
- Mikael's Blessing
- Ardent Censer

Will show your total Heal and Shield power. Example:

[image: Image of Mikael's Blessing's tooltip, with heal and shield power visible]

Strangely, some items that grant Heal and Shield power do *not* show this in their tooltip. Examples:

- Redemption
- Chemtech Purifier
- Moonstone Renewer (doesn't grant S&H power on its own, but adds extra depending upon how many Legendary items you have, and shows that added value, not your total)

Additionally, the Revitalize rune, which grants an extra 5% Heal and Shield power, will also show your total in its tooltip:

[image: Image of Revitalize tooltip]

---

### Old answer, outdated

#### There is no way to see this value

While it's considered an actual statistic, and has been in the game for almost a full year, this value is not represented anywhere in the in-game advanced statistics menu (available by holding the <kbd>C</kbd> key while in-game).

The only way to keep track of how much additional shield/heal power you have is to keep a rough estimate in the back of your mind. It would be really great if this was visible *somewhere* though...

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I find it on description panel of healing items, not sure if it's only avaliable for Chinese server though.

(Look in pic you can find `治疗效果和护盾强度总和：40%`, which translates to `heal and shield power in total: 40%`. )

[image]